# Понимание — сестра моя

Tags: грамматика

Можно ли ассоциировать слова среднего рода посредством женского и мужского?
Например, "понимание — сестра моя" или "понимание — брат мой". Как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что это хорошая идея. Как ни сложна метафора по сути, но грамматику соблюдать всё же следует. Понимание - оно (моё) и уподобляться должно чему-то сопоставимому, лучше в среднем роде, а не живому существу, принадлежащему к одному из двух полов.

Скорее всего Вы имеете в виду понимание не в значении "мыслительная способность", а понимание как сочувствие, способность взглянуть на мир глазами другого. Понимание -это тип человеческих отношений, которым присуще адекватное отражение слов и действий друг друга, совпадение взглядов и суждений, согласие в поступках, а также взаимно терпимое, взаимопрощающее поведение в случае разногласий. Взаимопонимание – основа дружбы и любви людей, их взаимодействия в учебных и трудовых коллективах.

Если хочется сказать о близости такого типа отношений, можно сказать: ***"Я - само понимание"***, *"Понимание - то, что мне близко в отношениях людей"*, *"Понимание - самое главное в отношениях"*и т.д.

Может быть, Вас вдохновила метафора Пастернака "сестра моя жизнь", но она легко расшифровывается: здесь он изображает мир как отражение человеческих переживаний.

Или у него же  в стихотворении «Лесное»:

Я – уст безвестных разговор,

Как слух, подхвачен городами;

Ко мне, что к стертой анаграмме,

Подносит утро луч в упор.

Но мхи пугливо попирая,

Разгадываю тайну чар:

Я – речь безгласного их края,

Я – их лесного слова дар.

О, прослезивший туч раскаты,

Отважный, отроческий ствол!

Ты – перед вечностью ходатай,

Блуждающий – я твой глагол.

Человек может быть уподоблен миру природы или чувству, но понятия должны быть сопоставимы, а ассоциации прозрачны, понятны тем, кто будет читать.

Comment: Вот место, которое я хочу показать вам: "Скажи мудрости, Ты сестра моя; и понимание назови родственницей твоей: "

Comment: Это у Вас перевод неверный, в книге Притчей Соломона: «Скажи мудрости: "Ты сестра моя!" и разум назови родным твоим, Чтобы они охраняли тебя от жены другого, от чужой, которая умягчает слова свои» (Прт. 7:4–5).
https://molitva-bogu.ru/pritchi-7-glava/